# Count Distinct Over Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two CTEs . The following is the output of my first CTE.

```
| ORDER_NUMBER | ORDER_FLAG | EMPLOYEE | PRODUCT_CATEGORY | SALES  |
|--------------|------------|----------|------------------|--------|
| 3158132      | 1          | Don      | Newpaper Ad      | 16.00  |
| 3158132      | 1          | Don      | Magazine Ad      | 15.00  |
| 3158132      | 0          | Don      | TV Ad            | 0.00   |
| 3158132      | 1          | Don      | Billboard Ad     | 56.00  |
| 3006152      | 1          | Roger    | TV Ad            | 20.00  |
| 3006152      | 0          | Roger    | Magazine Ad      | 0.00   |
| 3006152      | 1          | Roger    | Newspaper Ad     | 214.00 |
| 3012681      | 1          | Ken      | TV Ad            | 130.00 |
| 3012681      | 0          | Ken      | Magazine Ad      | 0.00   |
| 9818123      | 1          | Pete     | Billboard Ad     | 200.00 |
```

I'm attempting to count the distinct order numbers and the sales amount by employee.  The order flag will be either `1` or a `0`.  If sales are greater than `0.00` the order flag will be set to `1`.

My desired output.

```
| Employee | Sales  | Orders |
|----------|--------|--------|
| Don      | 87.00  | 1      |
| Ken      | 130.00 | 1      |
| Pete     | 200.00 | 1      |
| Roger    | 234.00 | 1      |
```

I was attempting to do a combination of distinct, case, and concat statements without any luck.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something.  Is this all you want: `select employee, sum(sales), count(distinct order_number) from cte group by employee` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
with cteTotalSales (...) as ()
select employee, 
   case when (sum(sales)) > 0 
     then 1 else 0 as Orders, 
 sum(sales)
from cteTotalSales
group by employee
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be as simple as :

```
with cte as (...)
select 
    employee, 
    sum(sales),
    count(distinct order_number)
from cte 
group by employee
```

Answer (score 0):

This query would work for you

```
SELECT 
  EMPLOYEE,
  SUM(SALES) SALES,
  1 AS ORDERS
FROM 
  YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY 
  EMPLOYEE
```

you can replace your subquery with YOUR_TABLE.

```
SELECT 
  EMPLOYEE,
  SUM(SALES) SALES,
  1 AS ORDERS
FROM 
(
  SELECT * FROM ...
)
GROUP BY 
  EMPLOYEE
```